# GPE 3.2 release?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Is there any update on when GPE 3.2 will be released? I've read that it was supposed to be released mid January but still no sign of it? I'm running Eclipse Juno but App engine connected to android is not working. I'm trying to develop an android app with a google app engine backend but cannot progress until the new release.

Any advise/notification greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

February 13, 2013: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/release_notes#v3.2.0 and of course there are many more recent releases.